# Updating UI objects in NSURLSession (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am trying to update a `UITextField` (or any UI element) after an `NSURLSession` is complete. For Xcode 6 I was told to always update the UI elements in the main thread. So after pressing a button, the textfield would be disabled, then re-enabled after the task has finished.

Now I am getting an error on the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` with Xcode 7. Has the method for updating UI elements changed in Xcode 7 or has accessing the main thread been changed?

Here is my code, any help is appreciated:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    usernameTextField.delegate = self
    ... 
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    addUserButton.enabled = false

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(...
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = ...
    request.HTTPBody = ...

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.myTextField.enabled = true
        })
    ...
    }
}
```

EDIT: The error I am getting is:

```
MyAppName was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
```

Comment: " am getting an error" What error are you getting???

Comment: So you are trying to debug (breakpoints and stepping) in a Release build? That's your problem. It's nice of them to point it out! It used to be that Release build debugging just mysteriously didn't work. Anyhow, it has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Are you telling me that I spend hours thinking I'm a terrible programmer when the new xcode is at fault? Do I just wait for a update to xcode then?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Xcode. Just don't try to debug a Release build, that's all.

Comment: I'm not debugging xcode...? I am just hitting run and getting this error after navigating through my app. I run into this error after clicking the actual button in my app. Is there maybe something I change in my settings?

Comment: But my point is, this is just a warning of some sort. It's not an error - you can compile, and you don't crash, right? So ... If it runs fine, ignore it.

Comment: This causes my app to crash while the project is running.

Comment: So what's the crash log when that happens? (Gosh, this is the question I asked you at first, 2 hours ago...)